# Cross-compiling Apache Thrift Program for armhf

Tags: cross-compiling, thrift, beagleboard

I am on x86 trying to cross compile a apache thrift program written in C++ for armhf. I installed `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` and `g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf` through `apt-get`, but when I use them to compile my program, I get

`skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libthrift.so when searching for -lthrift`

so I tried configuring thrift to compile a armhf-compatible libthrift.so using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743482/how-to-cross-compile-thrift-for-arm), so in bash:

`./configure CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --prefix=/BBB/thrift --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-cpp CFLAGS="-g -O2 -I$DIR/include" LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/lib`

but then I got:

`checking for libevent >= 1.0... configure: error: in 'home/xic/thrift-0.9.0': configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling`

so then I successfully compiled [libevent](https://github.com/libevent/libevent), but it still wouldn't work. Looking into thrift's `config.log`, I see

`/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

so apparently I need to cross-compile flex as well. Is this really the best way of doing this, or are there any faster/easier ways?

ps. I am cross-compiling for the Beaglebone Black, which uses armhf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thrift 0.9.0 is broken for cross compilation- it's got raftloads of static paths in the Autoconf test scripting.

There is a bug in their Jira on the subject, but things haven't progressed very far (Basically asking if I'd set the --includedir of all things...  (Hint: Cross compile doesn't use you dinking around with that on an Autotools config- and the first thing they should've done was go looking for fixed paths off of the host))

You can't turn off PHP building which screws up even further than this.  Shame, really, I kind-of needed a one-stop-shop for this and Google and the community at large have dropped the ball on this (RPC is a joke...how many differing implementations- and none of them support C/C++/Python/C# at the same time compatibly...).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up compiling natively on the beaglebone, but because the apache site doesn't give the package names for opkg (they use apt-get), I had to search for them individually. RPC documentation is seriously lacking...

Comment: Yeah, they only recently did work on sorting out at least part of the screwups on cross compilation (If only they'd quit using Autotools...sigh...) within the last three weeks, based on the emails I recently got on the bug I filed.  It's got potential, but it's not getting the care it needs- including the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

On my system, I installed `libfl` by running the following command, which should be easier than manually cross-compiling flex.

```
sudo xapt -a armhf -m libfl-dev
```

In order to fix the `cannot run test program while cross compiling` problem, you can either build Thrift without libevent support (if that is an option for you) by passing `--without-libevent` to `configure`, or you can modify `aclocal/ax_lib_event.m4` by replacing the use of `AC_RUN_IFELSE` with `AC_LINK_IFELSE`. Note that you will have to make a similar change in `aclocal/ax_lib_zlib.m4` unless you pass `--without-zlib` to `configure`. Don't forget to run `autoconf` after modifying the files in `aclocal`.

After making these changes you will likely encounter these compile errors:

> /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.6.3/cstdlib:119:11: error: '::malloc' has not been declared
>   /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.6.3/cstdlib:127:11: error: '::realloc' has not been declared

IMO, the easiest way to fix this is by removing the following lines from `configure.ac`:

```
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_REALLOC
```

Again, you'll have to run `autoconf` after deleting the lines from `configure.ac`.

Finally, you can re-run `configure` with your chosen options. On my system, I ran:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-cpp --without-tests \
   --without-qt4 --without-c_glib --without-ruby --without-python
```

You will need the `--without-tests` option to avoid problems caused by the build attempting to run armhf test binaries on your x86 build machine.

I passed the remaining `--without-*` options to avoid having to install extra dependencies. If you don't require QT, Glib, Ruby, and Python support, I recommend you do the same to simplify your build.

Comment: And for the latest thrift, turn off tests is `--enable-tests=no`

Comment: At the time I was trying to do this, it didn't work correctly for --without-tests.  They fixed it in more recent versions as indicated by @wilbeibi